# Mysql: Merging two similar tables with overlapping unique columns

Tags: mysql, merge, union

I have compiled two tables with plant names from different sources (A and B), which I want to merge into a third table (C). Table A and B both use the species name as a unique value, and contain Dutch names as well. Like this:

```
SPECIES           | DUTCH NAME
Ligustrum vulgare | Wilde liguster
Linaria vulgaris  | Vlasbekje
Linnaea borealis  | Linnaeusklokje
```

I want to merge these tables, but they have a lot of species in common. I want to give A priority over B, and only add to A if B has a species that A lacks. However, if a species in A doesn't have a Dutch name, than I want to add the Dutch name from B, if it's available. The species column in the new table is also set to unique.

I bet this needs to be done with UNION, and I did look around for examples, but I guess I am a bit too brain-fried to get it. What should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO c (species, dutch)
SELECT species, COALESCE(a.dutch, b.dutch)
FROM ( SELECT species FROM a
       UNION 
       SELECT species FROM b ) AS all_species
LEFT JOIN a USING (species)
LEFT JOIN b USING (species);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7f2dea9f56071c4dc0dd9abc93360624

Comment: Close! It does skip the cases where a species in B is already in A and it adds the extra B's. But it doesn't include de Dutch name when species from B are added. So, if a record comes from A goes I see "Abies amabilis | Pacifische zilverspar" and when it comes from B I see "Abies amabilis 'Spreading Star' |     ".

Comment: @DiederikSlob True. I didn't take it into account that 2nd NATURAL JOIN will join by 2 columns. Answer corrected, fiddle added. Check - maybe some combination is skipped?